# jsTree search query for child nodes only

Tags: jstree, jstree-search

I am using jsTree with the search plugin. Now I want the search to only match child nodes and not parents nodes.

This is what I've implemented:

```
"search": {
        case_insensitive: true,
        show_only_matches: true,
        search_leaves_only: true,
    }
```

Here's an example of my tree:

```
▼ Parent1
    └ child 1
  ParentABC
▼ Parentxyz
    └ child abc
```

`ParentABC` has no child node and if I search for "abc", both `ParentABC` and `child abc` is shown but the expected result should have been `child abc` only.

`search_leaves_only: true` works great on the child nodes because they have no child nodes themselves. jsTree considers a node as leaf when it has no child node.

So in what way can I make my search query for child nodes only?

**EDIT:**
**SOLUTION**

I just had to make use of `search_callback` with a custom function. Here it is:

```
"search": {
        show_only_matches: true,
        search_callback: function (searchString, node) {
            if (node.parent != "#" && node.text.toUpperCase().includes(searchString.toUpperCase()) == true) {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
```

The way I'm populating my tree is with JSON data and all my parent nodes have the attribute `parent` as `"#"`. `case_insensitive: true` does not work anymore, that's why I use `toUpperCase()`